# Filtering logs based on the contents of a message field

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Hello I am using kibana to search through logs. Each of our logs have a `message` field. I am able to find the log statements generated by a specific log statement in my Java code. I can do this by searching for `Building request for customerId:`.

This returns a list of results of the following form:

```
Building request for customerId: some:id
Building request for customerId: some:id
Building request for customerId: some:id
Building request for customerId: some:id 
Building request for customerId: some:id
```

Now I want to only find the log statements that contain a specific word. In this case -1.

How can I do this? Is there some kind of special lucene syntax that I need to use?

Comment: Why not just "Building request for customerId" AND "-1" or "Building request for customerId:-1". It is not clear how your log line is, especially: "customerId: some:id". What does "some:id" mean?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search in some specific field in Kibana you should follow [Kibana Query Language](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/kuery-query.html).

Very simple example in your case would be

```
message:-1
```

In case if you have tokenized your data properly, otherwise you would be needed to search a substring with a wildcards (caveat, this is very **inefficient**, tokenize data properly):

```
message:*-1 AND “Building request for customerId”
```

Comment: thanks, but I only want the log statements that only contain `Building request for customerId` and `-1`.